# Search scope (polymorphic) of RelatedTo field (What) in Task and Entity SObjects

Tags: apex, picklist, tasks, event, polymorphic

How can I retrieve values (objects names) held in *search scope (Polymorphic pick list)* of '**Related To**' field (what) defined in **Task** and **Entity** SObjects using Apex?

[image: want to retrieve these all field values of search scope shown in red marked area]

[image: Search Scope pick list]

Please help me out for the same I have tried a lot but enable to find the solution.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
Set<Schema.SObjectType> objActivityAllowed = new Set<Schema.SObjectType();
String objectNames = '';
for(Schema.SObjectType objectType : Task.WhatId.getDescribe().getReferenceTo()){
    objActivityAllowed.add(objectType);
    objectNames += '\n' + objectType;
}
System.debug(objectNames);
```

***This code will retrieve all the objects which Allow Activity checkbox is checked and shown in search scope of 'Related To' field (What) of Task.***